# How to install or update Grub after Windows installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a laptop running only Ubuntu, but now for some reason I needed Windows so I installed it and everything else works but Grub. How do I get my computer dual booting?

When I installed Ubuntu, I can remember that I needed to create password to Secure boot.

I tried to update Grub but the menu where you can choose Ubuntu/win doesn't appear.

Comment: Are both UEFI or both (old) BIOS/CSM/legacy? Can you boot either one from UEFI/BIOS boot menu? Did you run `sudo update-grub` ? Is Windows fast startup or hibernation off? Otherwise grub's os-prober cannot see the Windows install. If new Windows is bitlocker off?

Comment: Does this help? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/1684306)

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. Thanks. Sometimes you are so lost that you don't even know what keywords to use while searching.

Answer (score 0):

1- Disable fast startup in windows

2- After installing Windows, go to your motherboard firmware and put
Ubuntu first and save the settings.

3-

```
sudo os-prober

sudo update-grub
```

Note: My English is very bad. :)